# How to detect which /dev/input/eventX is the touchpad in Android/Linux?

Tags: android, linux, usb, device

I'm going to read the stream from touchpad, I know I can do it through /dev/input/eventX, but how can I determine which one represents the touchpad and which one represents the keypad?Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ioctl` on the entries in `/dev/input`. The various functions seem to be sporadically implemented, but `code=ioctl(fd, EVIOCGNAME(sizeof(buf)), buf);` will give you a name at least.

Actually, only root can do iotctl on /dev. It's better to enumerate /sys/class/input and get the name entries.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I find the touchpad:
look for the list of the id's of all devices.

```
xinput --list
```

Find the id of the touchpad.
For example, my touchpad is in id=12
then

```
xinput --list-props 12 | grep "Device Node"
```

and it should show you the /dev/input/event* that you are looking for.